# I want to slightly tweak my PACE automatic page load progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, loader, manual

I found a great plugin for a page loader, only the jquery is so overwhelming I don't know where to begin to execute a small change.

Basically it's a bar that loads on the top of the page, but when finished loading I'd like the bar to stay instead of fade like it's programmed to do.

Any ideas?
Here is the plugin link: http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/
and I have been using the Flat Top theme.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `ghostTime` option in pace to be a big value. E.g.

```
<script data-pace-options='{ "ghostTime": 10000000 }' src='http://github.hubspot.com/pace/pace.js'></script>
```